# Azure Active Directory Block Signin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am a user manager in my AAD.
I've got few users that are block from signing in

[image]

after running `Set-AzureAdUser -objectid ********.onmicrosoft.com -accountEnabled $true` it is not longer block from sign in, but from the server I can see

[image]

So I cannot use this account to log in into any computer in the domain. Why aren't this options synced? What can I do to fix so?

Comment: Is the account synchronized from on-premises to Azure AD?

Comment: No, they were all created via the Azure Portal and blocked from Powershell

Comment: Then what does the "server" mean?

Comment: Just an on-premise windows server machine I use to view users and GPOs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
NSG blocked the DC from synchronizing with AAD